# install sqlite3 on mac os x?

Tags: database, macos, sqlite, installation

I am trying update my version of sqlite3 on mac os x 10.5.7  I downloaded the source code that is recommended for unix and unix like programs.  I followed the compile and install directions in the readme file and everything seems to work fine.  However, when i check the version number of sqlite3 it remains at 3.4.0 (the old version).  Why is this? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely you installed it to a different location to the original — one that either appears later in the $PATH or not at all.

Comment: how do i determine where the appropriate location to install it is??

Comment: You examine your $PATH (and then think uninstalling the old version and symlinking the new one to a location in the $PATH).